# Building Calculator, getting Cannot set property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties, calculator

I am building a Calculator and I keep getting this error, I've tried typing it a few different ways but I couldn't figure it out, help, please!

```
const calculator = {
  displayValue: '0',
  firstOperand: null,
  waitingForSecondOperand: false,
  operator: null,
};

function updateDisplay() {
  const display = document.querySelector('.calculator-screen');
  display.value = calculator.displayValue;
}

updateDisplay();
```

I get the error on the

```
  display.value = calculator.displayValue;
```

this is the html for the file

```
<div class="calculator">
            <input type="text" class="calculator-screen" value = "0" disabled />
            <div class="calculator-keys">        
                <button type="button" class="operator" value="+">+</button>
                <button type="button" class="operator" value="-">-</button>
                <button type="button" class="operator" value="*">&times;</button>
                <button type="button" class="operator" value="/">&divide;</button>
```

Comment: Make sure your HTML has `.calculator-screen` class, I think `document.querySelector('.calculator-screen'); ` is returing null/undefined, please check

Comment: Do you have an element with the class `calculator-screen`? If you post a working example, it'll be easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

That error means that this line:

```
const display = document.querySelector('.calculator-screen');
```

Is returning null. So when you do this:

```
display.value = calculator.displayValue;
```

You're really saying:

```
null = calculator.displayValue;
```

Try logging the value and check for yourself:

```
function updateDisplay() {
  const display = document.querySelector('.calculator-screen');
  console.log('display: ', display); // this is probably 'null'
  display.value = calculator.displayValue;
}
```

I'm guessing you don't have a selector with the class `.calculator-screen`. Double-check the spelling or post the relevant HTML so I can confirm.

Here is your code, it seems to work fine I don't get an error so I'm not sure what's going on on your end:

```js
const calculator = {
  displayValue: '0',
  firstOperand: null,
  waitingForSecondOperand: false,
  operator: null,
};

function updateDisplay() {
  const display = document.querySelector('.calculator-screen');
  display.value = calculator.displayValue;
}

updateDisplay();
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
    <input type="text" class="calculator-screen" value = "0" disabled />
    <div class="calculator-keys">        
        <button type="button" class="operator" value="+">+</button>
        <button type="button" class="operator" value="-">-</button>
        <button type="button" class="operator" value="*">&times;</button>
        <button type="button" class="operator" value="/">&divide;</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey I updated the file with the bit of HTML that the code is referring to. thankyou for the help!

Comment: @LucasO I ran your code and there is no error, are you sure that you are including the `<script>` tag in the right place? If you are loading it before that chunk of HTML you are trying to select, it will throw that error. Make sure the `<script>` tag is at the very bottom of your document, right before the closing `<body>` tag. You can see from the snippet in my answer that no errors are shown.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `document.querySelector` is not finding the element you need.

This error means probably `display` is null when you try to set it's value, and the only thing that could cause this is the corrector not finding the selection you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to the disabled property of the input html tag. Remove the disabled attribute and try if it works.